# yml pluralization symfony2

Tags: symfony, twig, translation

I have this yml translation file:

```
follower:
  one: 'Follower'
  other: 'Followers'
```

And in my twig template I have this simple statement:

```
{{ 'app.activity.follower'|transchoice(1) }}
```

Currently the output is app.activity.follower. It's possibile to divide in more range than 3(zero, one, other)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is my xliff example:

```
        <trans-unit id="11">
            <source> app.activity.follower </source>
            <target>{0} No Follower|{1} Follower|[2,Inf] Followers</target>
        </trans-unit>
```

Hope this help

Comment: that is not the answer... he ask for yml not xliff

Comment: Hi @Emiliano see my new answer and check if could respond to your needed

Answer (score 0):

An example with the yaml syntax:

```
app:
    activity
        follower:
            time_limit: '{0} No Follower|{1} Follower|[2,Inf] Followers'
```